# clicking on Save as option in internet explorer using python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, automation

I'm trying to automate the process of downloading a bunch of files. i am using Internet explorer version 11.(which is the only way no other browser is compatible). The part until download is automated, but when the download link is clicked the IE pop ups a window showing weather to open,save,save as option.

---

Is there any python code where i can access the currently open IE and click on the save as button inside the window pop up,
here is a snap of the window pop up
[image]
i have to click on the down arrow near to save
[image]
this is my process that causes error every time i automate,
can anybody provide any help

---

**Huge thanks in advance**

Comment: how are you able to click on save. I am having this same issue. I am unable to click on Open. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit
Found the better/Easier way. Also I wrapped the invoke method in a try statement so you can use this with you other code and it will not try to click save/save as until the buttons are available.

To Click the Save Button:

```
import uiautomation as uia

SaveBtn = uia.SplitButtonControl(SearchDepth=4, Name = 'Save')

#wrap up the Invoke statement to try until the box shows up
while True:
    try:
        SaveBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()
    except LookupError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        break
```

To Click the Drop Down to click Saveas and save to location:

```
import uiautomation as uia

SaveLocation = "C:\\Foobar\\FoobarDrive\\FobarMagic\\""
savestr = "Foobar.xlsx
#Click the Saveas Button on Internet Explorer Window

#clicking the down arrow next to save
SaveBtn = uia.SplitButtonControl(SearchDepth=5, Name = '6')

    #wrap up the Invoke statement to try until the box shows up
while True:
    try:
        SaveBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()
    except LookupError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        break

    #Find/map saveas button and click the saveas option
SaveasBtn = uia.MenuItemControl(SearchDepth=2, Name = 'Save as')
SaveasBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()

    #Find Save as dialog and click on address bar
Savedlg = uia.WindowControl(SearchDepth=1, Name = 'Save As')

    #Name File
FileName = Savedlg.EditControl(SearchDepth=7,Name='File name:')
FileName.SendKeys(savestr)

    #Click on the Previous locations button to activate the Addressbar
PrevLocBtn = Savedlg.ButtonControl(SearchDepth=7,Name = 'Previous Locations')
PrevLocBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()

    #Find the Address bar and clear it out
Addressbar = Savedlg.EditControl(SearchDepth=8, Name = 'Address')
Addressbar.SendKeys('{Back}')

    #Define Save Location and Send the string to the addressbar
Addressbar.SendKeys(SaveLocation)

    #Click go to directory button
Navigatebtn = Savedlg.ButtonControl(SearchDepth=6, Name= 'Go to ' + '"' + SaveLocation + '"')
while True:
    try:
        Navigatebtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()
    except LookupError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        break

#Click Saveas Dlg Save Button
SaveBtn = Savedlg.ButtonControl(SearchDepth=2, Name="Save")
SaveBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()

#Overwrite the old file if it exists
confirm = Savedlg.WindowControl(SearchDepth=2, Name = 'Confirm Save As')
confirmbtn = confirm.ButtonControl(SearchDepth=2, Name = 'Yes')

while True:
    try:
        confirmbtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()
    except:
        break
```

How to open a file

```
#Click the Save Button on Internet Explorer Window

    #clicking the save button itself.
OpenBtn = uia.SplitButtonControl(SearchDepth=4, Name = 'Open')

    #wrap up the click statement to try until the box shows up
while True:
    try:
        OpenBtn.GetInvokePattern().Invoke()
    except LookupError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WebDriver has no capability to access the IE Download dialog boxes presented by browsers when you click on a download link or button. But, we can bypass these dialog boxes using a separate program called "[wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)". More details, you could check [this article](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html).